# Pass a file as a parameter and read it from a constructor

Tags: c++, file, input, constructor, ifstream

I am having issues passing a file through to a constructor

```
#include "WordList.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

WordList::WordList(ifstream& infile){}

-----
int main()
{
    WordList w1("input.txt");
}
```

Here the error is showing:

```
No instance of constructor matches the argument list, the argument types are (const char[10])
```

How can pass a file through a constructor then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ifstream strm ("input.text", ifstream::in) ;
 WordList w1 (strm) ;
```

You could also define WordList's constructor to take istream & as the parameter to generalize the routine.

Comment: Why cant I pass only "input.txt" as an argument like

Comment: Wordlist w1("input.txt")

Comment: Because (a) `ifstream`'s constructors are explicit and cannot be used for implicit conversions, and (b) even if an implicit conversion were allowed, it would use a temporary object, which can't bind to a non-const lvalue reference.